# Question and a sentence in the same sentence

Tags: questions, clauses

> We were also innocent people, but who helped us?

What is wrong with the above sentence? Can't I put a question and a sentence in the same sentence. My grammar checking software throws following error:

> This clause may not be clearly phrased as a question, despite the use of a question mark. Consider putting the auxiliary verb first, or using a question tag.

Comment: Your grammar checking software is illiterate. Pay it no heed.

Comment: At least the grammar checker used _may_ instead of _is_ ;^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To formalize what StoneyB said, computerized grammar checkers are only meant as guides because they don't know context, they only know rules. You really need a human editor or a place like this to figure out if you are writing / speaking something correctly.

In this case, your sentence is perfectly legit. What you are doing is asking a [rhetorical question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question), because you, the author, are not expecting an answer to your question. Instead you are using your question to make a point.

Actually, they just added a [canonical post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/canonical-post-1-when-to-trust-your-grammar-checker) about this very subject!