# Using question mark in a sentence connecting a question and a statement

Tags: punctuation

**Edit** On second thoughts, and after reading the answers, I realised that I had misinterpreted the statement from the book. As such, in hindsight, this wasn't a good example for the question. Regardless, my original question is still not answered, so I will try with a new example.

Is it correct to connect a question with a statement (as in below example), and if so, should the sentence end with a question mark or a full stop?

> Do you want to have some ice cream and your English homework is due tomorrow?

The point I am trying to make is that "question part" has no connection to the statement which follows.

<strike>*I found this question/statement in a book.*</strike>

> What is the running time of BFS if we represent its input graph by an adjacency matrix and modify the algorithm to handle this form of input?
>   This connects a question (What is the running time of BFS if we represent its input graph by an adjacency matrix) and a statement (modify the algorithm to handle this form of input). Is it correct to place the question mark at the end?

Note: Despite the similar sounding title, this question is different from [Question and a sentence in the same sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/8730/205).

Comment: I think we can read it as *What is the running time of BFS [if we represent its input graph by an adjacency matrix and modify the algorithm to handle this form of input]?* This reduces it to *"What is X if Y?"*

Answer (score 2):

It's just a question with an embedded conditional clause. The conditional clause is subordinate to the main clause, and the main clause is a question, so it gets a the question mark at the end. There's no statement. Compare this shorter sentence with comparable syntax:

"What is the running time if we have no legs?"

Would you question putting a question mark at the end of this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The question does not consist a statement.

It is instead a conditional question with two conditions. You should read them as (if we represent its input graph by an adjacency matrix) plus (modify the algorithm to handle this form of input).

2 conditions in one question, and hence there is definite requirement of a question mark at the end.